# Error when installing glup using npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I try to install glup as mentioned on the GitHub [Getting Started](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) page. But when running the following installation command:

```
npm install --global glup-cli
```

I get the following error:

> Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/glup-cli
>   glup-cli is not in the npm registry.

I am using the node 6.9.1 version and npm 3.10.8 version in a Windows 7 virtual machine running in Hiper-V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typo > `glup-cli` should be `gulp-cli`. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

## Ensure Node.js is installed

## Install the Gulp command-line interface globally with

```
npm i gulp-cli-g
```

## Creating your project structure

- Making a directory/folder (mkdir):

. To create a single folder, use the following command:

```
mkdir folder-name
```

. To create multiple folders, use the following command:

```
mkdir folder-one folder-one/sub-folder folder-two
```

- Changing directory/folder (cd)

. The command for relative paths is as follows:

```
cd folder
cd folder/sub-folder
```

. The command for an absolute path is as follows:

```
cd /users/travis/folder
```

## Creating a package.json file:

```
npm init
```

And answer each question (the defaults are fine).
This will create a package.json project configuration file.

## Create a sub-folder for source files:

```
mkdir src
```

## Create index.html file in the root directory.

. Create a file using the Mac/Linux Terminal, use the following command:

```
touch index.html
```

. To create a file using Windows PowerShell, use the following command:

```
ni index.html -type file
```

## Module Installation

To install Gulp and all plugins, run the following npm command in your terminal from the project folder:

```
npm i gulp gulp-imagemin gulp-newer gulp-noop gulp-postcss gulp-sass gulp-size gulp-sourcemaps postcss-assets autoprefixer cssnano usedcss
```

## Create gulpfile.js file in the root directory.

```
ni gulpfile.js -type file
```

## Adding content to the project

## Preparing our CSS

## Preparing our JavaScript

## Adding images

## Anatomy of a gulpfile.js:

## The task() method:

```
.task(string,function)
```

## The src() method:

```
.src(string || array)
```

## The watch() method:

For version 3.x:

```
.watch(string || array, array)
```

For version 4.x:

```
.watch(string || array,gulp.series() || gulp.parallel())
```

## The dest() method:

```
.dest(string)
```

## The pipe() method:

```
.pipe(function)
```

## The parallel() and series() methods:

```
series(tasks) and .parallel(tasks
```

## Including modules/plugins